# Can't change display backlight brightness

Tags: xubuntu

I'm using Xubuntu 20.04 LTS on Acer Athlon silver amd laptop. I can't change display backlight brightness using keys F3 / F4 or by menu panel. This may be caused by removing of Cinnamon-desktop-envernoment, I think. How should I fix this error?

Comment: Вы должны задать свой вопрос на английском языке на AskUbuntu ...

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install --reinstall xubuntu-desktop^` .